# var vm = this not working in this case

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I m using controllerAs, and I'm wondering why in this case, `var vm = this` isn't working (my guess is that it doesn't work for ionic related things) :

```
function TutorialCtrl($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'yo';

    vm.next = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };

    // Called each time the slide changes
    vm.slideChanged = function(index) {
      vm.slideIndex = index;
    };
  }
```

It does work with $scope, ofcourse. And my bind actually works for my test : `vm.title` (it is correctly displayed in my view). 
Can't find any info on that, can someone explain? I wish to get rid of all $scope but sometimes I just can't. Thanks  !

**EDIT**: I found my mistake ! In my view I forgot to add vm. on my methods... ofcourse it couldn't work ! :p

Comment: `controllerAs` means you gave the controller an alias. Thus, whenever you make reference to it you use the alias

Comment: Im fully aware of that lol, that doesn't explain why in this particular ionic case it doesn't work, and thats what I would like to know !

Comment: `vm.slideIndex = index;`; is this the line that is failing?

Comment: na man its all of these except vm.title. I read somewhere that its related to ionic... its no big deal tho, just wishing to know why it doesn't work with that :)

Comment: oh well...... 

Comment: I have the solution !! My html view wasn't setup, I forgot to add vm.mymethod... it works now ! and it makes sense aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake : in my view I forgot to bind vm to my methods (i.e. 
 : `vm.mymethod` ). Obviously it couldn't work.... all good now.

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer using controller as syntax and getting rid of references to `$scope` in controllers as well (for the eventual update to Angular2 and beyond). The way that I prefer to implement controllers using controller as is similar to what your described above with a few tweaks. As you can see, `$scope` is no longer needed to be imported and this should make the functions available in your template.

```
function TutorialCtrl($state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    var vm = {};
    vm.title = 'yo';

    vm.next = function() {
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };

    // Called each time the slide changes
    vm.slideChanged = function(index) {
        vm.slideIndex = index;
    };

    return vm;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work ahah but I knew it wouldn't.. I don't have to return vm (doesn't make sense). No worries tho !